# Tags aren't working correctly when writing or editing a question

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, internet-explorer, tag-autocomplete

I tried editing a question and the tags disappear from the "Tag" box - it behaves like a common text field. The same is happening when writing this question. I assume there's something wrong with the site?

[image]

Comment: No repro for  me  (Chrome/ Win 10)

Comment: I'm also unable to edit and save the edit, which I noticed just now as I tried to add: I was unable to post the question until I activated the checkbox to answer my own question. Then I was able to save.

Comment: Do you have any errors in the javascript console?  Also what browser and version?  Does it behave this way on all SE sites, or just one?

Comment: @Servy Windows 7, IE 11. Mmmm, how would I look for the JS errors? I don't browse with a console.

Comment: No repro, just edited your post. (Chrome / Win 10).

Comment: @Servy When I go into the Edit mode I get: SCRIPT1046: Multiple definitions of a property not allowed in strict mode
File: tageditornew.en.js, Line: 1, Column: 11462

Comment: I also get the SCRIPT1046 error in IE 11 (Win 7) and see the same issue with the tag field being plain text.

Comment: Also, the submit button for editing is disabled.

Comment: At least it does recognize tags when I edit tags directly, but no IntelliSense...

Comment: Additional issue: If I flag a comment, instead of the colored comment flag at the left I see the text "flag"

Comment: That issue I reproduced on Microsoft Edge too, and filed a bug report on Meta Stack Exchange: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/312797/flagging-a-comment-displays-the-word-flag-changes-to-image-of-red-flag-upon-r

Comment: Not reproduced on Win10 Opera54.0 (Trying to edit your question looks weird... Very meta. But that which is actually my UI looks as expected.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a typo snuck in last night... IE's diligent Strict Mode caught it when Chrome would not.

Typo banished, this should all be working as expected.